# Returning an AngularJS $q promise with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-promise, deferred

I have a service that wraps $http with my functions returning a deferred object.

My interface:

```
export interface MyServiceScope {
    get: ng.IPromise<{}>;
}
```

My class:

```
export class MyService implements MyServiceScope {

    static $inject = ['$http', '$log'];

    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService,
                private $log: ng.ILogService,
                private $q: ng.IQService) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$log = $log;
        this.$q = $q;
    }

    get(): ng.IPromise<{}> {
        var self = this;
        var deferred = this.$q.defer();

        this.$http.get('http://localhost:8000/tags').then(
            function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },
            function(errors) {
                self.$log.debug(errors);
                deferred.reject(errors.data);
            }
        );

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

The compilation is failing with the following error:

```
myservice.ts(10,18): error TS2420: Class 'MyService' incorrectly implements interface 'MyServiceScope'.
    Types of property 'get' are incompatible.
        Type '() => IPromise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'IPromise<{}>'.
            Property 'then' is missing in type '() => IPromise<{}>'.
```

For reference, [here is the IPromise](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/af81415504b4edce8dac8446d96857f8018c6e9f/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L1046) definition from DefinitelyTyped. The `IQService.defer()` call returns an `IDeferred` object, and then `deferred.promise` returns IPromise object.

I'm not sure if I'm using the wrong definitions in my interface, or not returning the deferred object the same way. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can skip all the `this. = ;` lines also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your interface you defined a property `get` and in the service implementation it's a function `get()`. What you probably want is a function, so the interface should be:

```
export interface MyServiceScope {
    get(): ng.IPromise<{}>;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. That was definitely the issue. Thanks for the quick help!