# TypeScript async/await vs JS tj/co

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, generator, co

Do I understand correctly that I do not need to use libs like tj/co in TypeScript to control flow, since I can use async/await? 
Using promises with generators is just a workaround for async/await?

Comment: $q.defer and resolve are fine for you. You can use IQService in type script. You should see this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237586/returning-an-angularjs-q-promise-with-typescript

Comment: In Node I can use just Promise<T> and async/await.

Comment: Why this question is about TS only? I guess this question can be more general to cover TS and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not need to use libs like tj/co in TypeScript to control flow, since I can use async/await?

Yes.

> Using promises with generators is just a workaround for async/await?

Yes. Generators and async runners were used in ES6 to emulate `async`/`await` and get the syntactic sugar everyone longed for. Now with ES8 you can `await` your promises directly.